# Issue in Ckeditor and php, while submitting the form

Tags: php, ckeditor

**Issue in FCK Editor Class Name**

```
In the below given code, I am able to update text inside the textarea.
```

But i want to use ckeditor, While i use the **class='ckeditor'**.  I can't get any value.

Do i miss anything ??

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
       var name=$("#txt").val();   // specify the id of your text field 
       $.post("test_post.php",
             {name: name}).done(function(data){
              $('#stage').html(data);
               }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
   <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
<div id='stage'></div>
   <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
 <textarea class="ckeditor" name="txt" id="txt">
</textarea>

   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
```

Here is my Php Code :

```
 <?php

 include ('conn.php');
 if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
 $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
{

$q = "UPDATE `test` SET `text` = '$name' where `sno`='1' ";
if(mysql_query($q))
{
echo 'success'.$q;
}
else
{
echo 'fail'.$q;
}
}
?>
```

For the testing purpose, i remove the class name and checked it works good, but while i include the class name it is not returning any value ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get value with `$("#txt").val()`

You have to get value from CKEditor instance :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.txt.getData();
```

---

```
$.post("test_post.php", {
    name: CKEDITOR.instances.txt.getData()
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#stage').html(data);
});
```